# Toggle image based on cookie value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using a couple of JS functions to set a cookie named `'visible'` with the value of either `yes` or `no`.

Essentially Im using these values to decide if a `<div>` is visible or hidden.

I've only just added the cookie, previously I had been using two images 1. Show 2. Hide as a button to hide and show the `<div>` like this:

HTML:

```
<img class="show" title="Show" alt="Show" src="images/show.png" />
<img class="hide" title="Hide" alt="Hide" src="images/hide.png" />
```

JQUERY:

```
  $("#tool").click(function() {
$(".help").slideToggle();
    $("#wrapper").animate({ opacity: 1.0 },200).slideToggle(200, function() {
     $("#tool img").toggle();
    });
  });
```

However I have now added the Cookie into the mix:

$("#tool").click(function() {
  if(get_cookie('visible')== null) {
    set_cookie('visible','no');
  } else {
    delete_cookie('visible');
  }
  $(".help").slideToggle();
  $("#wrapper").animate({ opacity: 1.0 },200).slideToggle(200, function() {
    $("#slider img").toggle();
  });
});

So the .toggle() no longer matches the state of the `<div>`

When the cookie value = no the `show.png` should be visible

When the cookie value = yes then the `hide.png` should be visible

Can anyone suggest how i can ammend this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things easier I just didn't delete the cookie. And simply set it every time.

```
$("#tool").click(function () {
    var cookie = get_cookie('visible');
    if (cookie == null) {
        set_cookie('visible', 'no');
        cookie = get_cookie('visible');
    }
    if (cookie.value == 'yes') {
        set_cookie('visible', 'yes');
        $(".help").slideDown();
        $("#wrapper").animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 200).slideDown(200, function () {
            $("#tool img").show();
        });

    } else {
        set_cookie('visible', 'no');
        $(".help").slideUp();
        $("#wrapper").animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 200).slideUp(200, function () {
            $("#tool img").hide();
        }

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0].src = get_cookie('visible') ? 'images/hide.png' : 'images/show.png';
```